# Multiple similar event handlers for input validation

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I want to reduce my repetitive code used to validate inputs values. For that I'm using:

- a class associated to the input
- a condition to validate the input value
- an event handler

First I declare the classes I'm using:

```
var inputNotNull = '.js-mandatory-notnull',
    input2Words = '.js-mandatory-2words',
    inputNumb = '.js-mandatory-numb';
```

Then I create an event handler for each class and each of them has the same pattern: Call the function `validateInput(event, thisInput, itsCondition)`

```
$(document).on('keyup change focusout', inputNotNull, function(e){
    var $xthis = $(this),
        condition = $xthis.val().length>0;
    validateInput(e, $xthis, condition); //treats the visual part of the input
});


$(document).on('keyup change focusout', input2Words, function(e){
    var $xthis = $(this),
        condition = $xthis.val().match(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ [A-Za-zÀ-ú]+/i);
    validateInput(e, $xthis, condition);
});

$(document).on('keyup change focusout', inputNumb, function(e){
    var $xthis = $(this),
        condition = this.value.match(/^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]?\d*$/);
    validateInput(e, $xthis, condition);
});
```

I was wondering how I could reduce this code. In this example I only show 3 classes, but on my code I have >20 classes. Is it possible to do something similar to "key:value" ("input:condition") and I would end up writing something like this:

```
var validations = {
    '.js-mandatory-notnull' : length > 0,
    '.js-mandatory-2words' : match(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ [A-Za-zÀ-ú]+/i),
    '.js-mandatory-numb' : match(/^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]?\d*$/),
}
```

And then somehow treat this object to reproduce what I wrote before.

In this example I'm talking about validations, but I would like to apply this knowledge into another repetitive code scenarios.

Comment: Something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ubqgz6zh/

Comment: @adeneo that's not what i want, this example i showed 3 classes, but currently i have more than 20 classes.

Comment: Could use a validation plugin and pop in your rules accordingly

Comment: .Validate jQuery plugin is not an option? https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: Why using an external plugin when I have my own code. I want to learn first how to do it, and only then use plugins.

Comment: go through source code of various validation plugins then to learn how they do it

Comment: In this example I'm talking about validations, but I would like to apply this knowledge into another repetitive code scenarios.

Comment: OK. it's a MIT License. With addMethod you can code your own rules or just read the code and maybe have a solution to this isue.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, you can't just add conditions to an object, and all those classes seems counterintuitive, you have to somehow pass something else, like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ubqgz6zh/1/

Comment: start by creating `types` of validation then in your object set `type` and either a function or regex depending on type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I am not sure what the `validateInput()` function is intending to do if the validation happens **before** you even call that code.

The essence of your problem is that you need to handle different events on an arbitrary set of fields that need to trigger a validation event.

That means, all you really should need to do from an event binding point of view is something like this

```
$('.target_element_selector').on('keyup change focusout', function(){
    validateInput(this);
});
```

Or for delegated binding:

```
$('.common_ancestor_selector').on(
    'keyup change focusout',
    '.target_element_selector',
    function(){
        validateInput(this);
    }
);
```

`this` in within this function context will have everything you need to know to perform a validation. From it you can reference the current value for the field, the type of validation rule that should be applied, and of course the element itself should you need to modify it (not discussed here).

Inside your validation method is where you should hold the logic on how validations occur, not outside of it, otherwise, why have the function at all?

Now for the validation method...

At it's simplest this method needs to: determine input value, determine validation to apply, and return validation result.

That could look something like this:

```
function validateInput(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    // My suggestion would be to set data properties on element
    // rather than classes to indicate validation enforcement.
    // This is easier than iterating through classes.
    var rule = $el.data('validation-rule');

    if(rule === 'undefined') {
        // there is no validation rule, so let's pass validation
        return true;
    }

    if(rule in validationFunctions){
        return validationFunctions[rule]( $el.val() );
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown validation rule "' + rule + '" specified.');
};
```

Which would work with a set of validation functions like this (note I am using arrow functions here which seem to lend brevity to this code).

```
// set of validation functions
var validationFunctions = {
    'not-null':
        value => { return value.length > 0; },
    'two-words':
        value => { return value.match(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ [A-Za-zÀ-ú]+/i); },
    'numb':
        value => { return value.match(/^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]?\d*$/); },
    // etc.
};
```

Elements could look like:

```
<input class="js-mandatory" data-validation-rule="not-null" ...>
```

So it is really easy for someone writing the front end to simply specify a given
validation rule and have the code automatically add this field to the set of fields being validated.

Note that this doesn't show how to change the display around the element, but that wasn't part of you original code, so I didn't expound on that area.

**Added**

- I just noticed in working on code example below that you are using `string.match()` when it might be better to use `/{regex}/.test()` to be able to return boolean (probably good to enforce this as requirement for all test validation functions).  This will likely perform better as well.
- Since you have clarified your use case, let me give a more practical example than what I gave above.  Here we build an `inputElementValidator` object that could be used on any element that supports `$.val()` and allows you to pass a callback to the validation function which it can call with success/failure.  This allows you to cleanly decouple your validation mechanism, making it potentially re-usable across multiple applications.

On your page itself, you simply instantiate your validator, define the callback you want to trigger in response to validation, and then attach event handler to call validation.

```
/*
 * Here is your class which could be included from separate file
 */
function inputElementValidator(validators) {
    this.validators = $.extend(this.defaultValidators, validators);
};

// class method(s)
inputElementValidator.prototype = {
    validate: function (el, callback) {
        var $el = $(el);
        // get validation to be applied from element attribute
        var rule = $el.data('validation-rule');

        if(rule === 'undefined') {
            // there is no validation rule, so let's pass validation
            return callback(el, true);
        }

        // validator must return boolean
        if(rule in this.validators){
            // callback must support two arguments - the element and validation status
            return callback(el, this.validators[rule]);
        }

        throw new Error(
            'Unknown validation rule "' + rule + '" specified.'
        );
    }
};

// class "static" property
inputElementValidator.defaultValidators: {
    'not-null':
        value => { return value.length > 0; },
    'two-words':
        value => { return /^[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ [A-Za-zÀ-ú]/.test(value); },
    'numb':
        value => { return /^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]?\d*$/.test(value); },
    // etc.
};


/*
 * Here is your code in your page
 */
// perhaps wrap in IIFE to make this self-contained scope
(function() {
    // first, set up validator with whatever rules above and beyond default
    var inputValidator = new inputElementValidator({
        'new-or-overridden-validation-rule':
            value => { return /* something */; }
    });

    // create your validation callback function
    // this is where you apply your logic to display validation success/failure
    function validationCallback(el, success) {
        if(success) {
            // do something with el or $(el)
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }

    // attach event handling
    $('.common_ancestor_selector').on(
        'keyup change focusout',
        '.target_element_selector',
        function() { inputValidator.validate(this, validationCallback); }
    );
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I forgot to explain: validateInput() treats the visual part of the element to show to the user what's wrong/right. Maybe validateInput() is not the best name for that. And in terms of performance, using data-attr is faster than different classes ? I read that classes are faster, so I used classes...

Comment: I did validateInput() function because to avoid repeating it each time I wrote  the event handler. Now that i only write it once, I can write the function directly on the event handler function.

Comment: @SandrinaPereira I do not prefer to use data attributes in a selector as classes would be prefered for this, and better from performance standpoint. However, if you are just doing direct lookups of a data attribute on an element, this should not be any performance concern (and you can oftentimes easily store the value in a javascript variable for additional reference - which is what jQuery actually does with `.data()`.   There may be good reason to keep your separate validation function rather than having it event handler.  This allows you to generalize your use of the validator on the page.

Comment: @SandrinaPereira Based on your comments, I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Actually i'm really thinking about create a plugin based on the code i've been building (and you guys helping me). When it's finished, i'll let you know :)

Comment: @SandrinaPereira what I have is not far removed from what you might need for a jQuery plug in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions for those validations:

```
var validations = {
    '.js-mandatory-notnull': function(val) {
        return val.length > 0;
    },
    '.js-mandatory-2words': function(val) {
        return val.match(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ [A-Za-zÀ-ú]+/i);
    },
    '.js-mandatory-numb': function(val) {
        return val.match(/^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]?\d*$/);
    }
}
```

And then install those via a loop:

```
$.each(validations, function(selector, validate) {
    $(document).on('keyup change focusout', selector, function(e){
        validateInput(e, $(this), validate(this.value));
    });
});
```

Comment: Btw, you probably want `test` not `match`

Comment: thanks! i'll check if this works and check the different between `test` and `match`

Comment: uau, it worked perfectly. my big doubt is how .each() parameters knew that you were refering the .class and the function(val). Then I read .each() documentation and it accepts 2 parameters: (object, callback). Thank you again!

Comment: @SandrinaPereira `validations` is the `object` and the function expression is the `callback`. Check the docs on how the callback is invoked. But you can use any looping mechanism, just make sure that it provides [a scope of the closure in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572)

Comment: In the regex, when using `i` flag there is no need to include both uppercase and lowercase range `A-Za-z` OR `i` flag can be removed.

Comment: @Tushar thanks for your tip. I'm still learning Regex